# Dart firebase AND equivalent

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My assumption was multiple where conditions make AND equivalent , as in

```
  .collection("Property")
  .where('FirebaseAuthId', isEqualTo: userId)
  .where('PropertyId', isEqualTo: PropertId);
```

but on analysing the firestore DB , this seems to work more like an OR .how can the AND achieved for updating document .

```
Future updateLastChatVisitTime(userId, PropertId) async {
  WriteBatch batch = Firestore.instance.batch();
  var _documentRef = await Firestore.instance
      .collection("Property")
      .where('FirebaseAuthId', isEqualTo: userId)
      .where('PropertyId', isEqualTo: PropertId);

    _documentRef.getDocuments().then((ds) async {
      if (ds != null) {
        ds.documents.forEach((value) {
          print('MAPPINGS are ${value.documentID}');
          batch.updateData(
              Firestore.instance
                  .collection("Property")
                  .document(value.documentID),
              {"LastVisitTime": DateTime.now().toUtc()});
        });
        await batch.commit().then((value) {
          print("Batch updateLastChatVisitTime update ok");
        }).catchError((err) {
          print('Error updateLastChatVisitTime update $err');
        });
      }
    });
}
```

Also this link from firebase says it acts like Logical AND , am confused , did I miss something
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

Comment: its my mistake , I overlooked an async variable 'userId' which was coming null , so this was acting like userId == null AND propId == 'xyz' , bt still it should not give any documents as I dont have any document with userID == null , it just acted like simple where()

Answer (score 0):

`.where()` query can *also* act as filters - they will *not* generally include records where a field is missing.  It's quite possible your records (which you do not show) are inconsistent; some may be missing one or the other of the fields.  I'm not sure what the compound index would create under the circumstances.

Comment: its my mistake , I overlooked an async variable 'userId' which was coming null , so this was acting like userId == null AND propId == 'xyz' , bt still it should not give any documents as I dont have any document with userID == null , it just acted like simple where()